Influence of irrelevant details on science
What are the assumptions/philosophical framework that allow us to dismiss the irrelevant details when formulating and testing a scientific theory? For example, somebody might claim that the laws of electromagnetism would be different, if tested in an experiment performed after a reciting a magic formula, or if the experiment is carried out by a particular person - say, a well-known celebrity. It seems that such claims are fallacious, but I struggle to formulate clearly the fallacy and when it is a fallacy and when not (some thing may indeed affect outcome of the experiment - in what relationship should they be with the theory?)

A fallacy is an error in logic. What you are talking about would be an error in judgment; so it wouldn't be called a fallacy.

@DavidGudeman informal fallacy?

@RogerV., no, it's not a fallacy of any kind. A fallacy is a mistake in logic, where logic is a form of reasoning that starts with premises and draws conclusions. The form of reasoning in question here is just a matter of judgment: what factors should be included in my experiment? There aren't premises to reason from, only your intuitions.

I can't help but feel that the three answers so far all seem to be too shallow, perhaps because they view this as a methodological problem when it is really an epistemological problem. You can't solve the methodological problem until you have resolved the epistemological problem of how you know that it is even possible to rule out any particular fact as relevant to any particular prediction.

@DavidGudeman the question was motivated by the discussion around this one - a scientist make confidently make predictions about many hypothetical situations without having ever testing exactly this setup... in fact, experimentally testing the specific setup might be even absurd, although it is highly illustrative in theory.

@MichaelHall by fallacy I mean the claim that changing parameters irrelevant to the phenomenon might affect the outcome of the experiment. The problem here is defining the irrelevance - while the relevant parameters are usually explicitly included in theory (e.g., as variables in the equations or conditions of applicability), the irrelevant parameters are not spelled, and one can invent an infinite number of them.

@MichaelHall I think people make too much out of casual mentioning of their preferred/disliked political figure, and are too quick to assume that it is meant in negative sense or even an invitation for a fight. But I changed the language to a more neutral.

"the relevant parameters are usually explicitly included in theory." Right, so everything else is excluded and irrelevant. However, if you claim that changing an irrelevant parameter will affect the outcome and it does, then by definition that parameter is relevant, right?  "one can invent an infinite number of them." Sure, but why would you?  Still unclear what you are asking, how to determine the relevance of parameters?  Or are you asking if thinking a parameter is relevant when it isn't is a fallacy?  Because if your reasoning is incorrect that's the definition of fallacy, right?

I guess that aspect of it seems self answering so I just don't see the confusion...

Reason in its most general sense is applied to scientific thinking. Thus, all specious arguments made can be whittled down by exposing fallacious thinking. For instance, anyone making a post hoc ergo propter hoc argument in scientific discourse will be exposed by others. And of course, scientists often rely on their intuitions. Furthermore concerns over ad hoc modifications to theory, worries over parsimony are common, and there are other criteria of a good scientific theory that guide thinkers. But good science is very much an art and not an algorithm.
There have been attempts to bring rigorous formal logic to bear on scientific practice, but they haven't been very successful. Hempel in his Aspects advocated the deductive-nomological model. Carnap introduced Ramsey sentences to try to suss out metaphysical nonsense. The logical positivists as a whole thought some logical order could be brought to empiricism and positivism, but post-postivistic thinkers like Quine, Kuhn, Hanson, and Feyerabend helped to destroy the ambition to have strong formal logical safeguards on the process of science.
Thus, the experiment still rules the roost in science, and the question of how science is done remains quite a complex affair of explanation in the philosophy of science. Specifically, the sciences (let's pluralize to recognize the plurality of methods at play among the natural, social, and formal sciences) seek to put explanatory inference to work. Another name of explanatory inference is inference to best explanation conflated by many authors with abductive reasoning.
As you're likely aware, practical and theoretical reason is largely defeasible (SEP), and it's sometimes difficult to figure out what one doesn't know. That means scientists are often trying to determine what the factors are and what they should be called in causal explanations. What everyone from physicists to psychologists do then is create experiments and vary conditions to see what sort of correlations emerge from testing. In his Doing Physics (GB), Martin Krieger details the strategies that physicists use when trying to determine what adequate theory is. It's complex, but I'll give you a fragment:

A handle onto the world is called a degree of freedom, whether it be the temperature of a gas, the position of a particle, or the orientation of a crystal. A degree of freedom is a direction for potential action... You want to arrange things so that the degrees of freedom you are talking about are the important ones. And hopefully, by your device and setup you have hidden or tamed the less important and potentially annoying degrees of freedom. (p.xii)

Here then, we see Krieger talking about the use of variables to determine correlations to build mathematical models. Correlations are one tremendously powerful tool for ruling out irrelevant phenomena. There are myriad probabilistic and statistical methods for making arguments about relationships between these "degrees of freedom". One renowned thinker on such techniques is Judea Pearl who wrote Causality (GB). These days, what we can learn from our data collections and models have been greatly enriched by machine learning. From WP:

ML finds application in many fields, including natural language processing, computer vision, speech recognition, email filtering, agriculture, and medicine.3 The application of ML to business problems is known as predictive analytics.

Thus, scientists hypothesize, attempt to build causal models (SEP) and other models in science (SEP), and then conduct experiments and collect data to figure out what is relevant and what is not. Thus, with a little algebra and a big data set, one can perform linear regression and draw conclusions about the relationships of things in the world. With peer-review, rigorous publications, and repeated experiments, scientists of all stripes then discard bad ideas, bad ontological primitives, bad definitions, and bad methods to improve our model of physical reality, a point that Karl Popper took to heart in his Conjectures and Refutations.

The dismissal of irrelevant details in scientific theory is based on several philosophical principles:
Parsimony: Keeping theories as simple as possible by excluding unnecessary factors; this is often referred to as Occam’s Razor.
A scientific theory should be as simple as possible while still explaining the observed phenomena. If extraneous details, like reciting a magic formula or the identity of the experimenter (such as a celebrity), are not necessary to explain the outcomes of the experiment, they are not included in the theory.
Reproducibility: Ensuring results are consistent across different contexts and experimenters. If a theory is valid, the same experiment should yield the same results regardless of the person conducting it, their background, or external conditions that are not physically linked to the phenomenon. (A claim that a well-known celebrity performing the experiment would lead to different results violates the principle of reproducibility unless there is a justifiable mechanism linking the celebrity’s presence to the physical conditions of the experiment.)
Causal Relevance: Focusing on factors that directly relate to the outcomes. Thus, a claim about the laws of electromagnetism changing because a particular person performs the experiment is dismissed as fallacious because there is no plausible causal mechanism by which the identity of the experimenter would influence electromagnetic fields or interactions. For a factor to be relevant, it must be part of the chain of physical causality in the phenomenon being studied.
Fallacy Avoidance: Rejecting claims based on logical errors like post hoc reasoning. If someone claims that the laws of electromagnetism change when a particular ritual is performed before an experiment, this falls into the post hoc fallacy unless there is a demonstrable causal connection. Science requires establishing such a connection through repeatable experiments and rational explanations based on known physical laws.
Theoretical Consistency: Maintaining coherence with well-established scientific knowledge. A theory that proposes a radical departure from known physics (like electromagnetism changing depending on a ritual) would need extraordinary evidence. In the absence of such evidence, the simpler explanation (that these factors are irrelevant) is preferred, following Occam’s Razor. The established laws of electromagnetism are based on a huge body of evidence and mathematical consistency. A claim that these laws change due to irrelevant factors would need to provide extremely strong evidence to be taken seriously, but lacking this, it is dismissed as inconsistent with established knowledge.
These principles form the backbone of scientific reasoning and allow us to sift through extraneous details to focus on what truly matters for explaining and predicting natural phenomena.

While scientists usually make quite excellent educated guesses at what parameters are irrlevant, they can usually not be ignored entirely. However, if you claim that it is relevant whether an experiment is performed by Donald Trump, it is you who needs to back up your claim with experimental data. And, of course, be assured that any scientist looking on your paper will be extremely sceptical (and most will probably never make it past its title...).
Now, how do we know that certain variable are irrelevant? There are a few different cases:

We have a theory that already makes precise predictions (= within the measurement errors). In that case, all variables not considered by the theory are irrelevant. For instance, think about the motions of the asteroids within the solar system. Given sufficiently precise measurements, we can calculate their future positions for very long times. This is the best case that we can hope for.

We have a theory, but the results vary from experimental setup to experimental setup. Like people in Mexico get one result, while the other team in Japan get a different one. Or, one day, the experiment yields one result, and the next day it yields another. Such deviations are a tell-tale sign that some variable that we thought was irrelevant, is actually relevant. It means that the theory is deficient. The "Hubble Tension" is a current example of this: Measuring the expansion rate using star/galaxy catalogues yields one value, while measuring it using the microwave background radiation yields a different one. Scientists are rather excited about what the cause for this will turn out to be (bad theory? bad data? bad implicit assumptions?). Proposals for what could be going on are a dime a dozen right now, and the field will probably not rest until the cause can be identified with confidence.

We have no theory, but experimental data. Like people with certain traits along with their genome sequences. In this case, we can still play the statistics game: Pick any combination of a genome position and a trait, and check whether there is a correlation between the genome variant and the trait. If there is none, we can be fairly certain that the different genome variants for this location are irrelevant for the trait. Unfortunately, it can be hard to get enough data for a significant result due to the noise in the data. As such, we can usually not be certain about what is relevant and what is not. The genome, for instance, may not be the only factor at play. The trait could be linked to mitochondial DNA, for example, or be a result of the microbes within the person's intestials, even when it's clearly a hereditary trait. Even pure chance of cell differentiation may be a relevant factor, as it is for the precise form of your finger prints!



Thank you. Indeed, in some respect my question is related to statistics: our conclusions are invariably based on studying a sample and generalizing to other situations. We need not perform the experiment under all imaginable and unimaginable circumstances to be sure that the theory is true. (I even think that such an attempt would defeat the very purpose of theory.)

@RogerV. No, that attempt would not defeat the purpose of the theory. In fact, we are constantly trying to disprove even the best of our theories, applying them to ever more extreme cases. Because any discrepancies that might show up (like the Hubble Tension) may be the starting point for a deeper understanding of our universe. And that's exciting to any true scientist! Also, it gives us confidence when we apply the theory in parameter regions that have already been tested rigorously. For instance, we know that general relativity works well around earth, the GPS in your cell phone proves that.

I am not talking about applying to extreme cases, but rather to all possible mundane situations. E.g., will a red car be faster than my yellow one?

@RogerV. That is indeed a very well tested area of parameters, so much so that virtually all scientists won't bother doing the experiment. Especially when there are so many other parameters that need to be controlled for, like air pressure, temperature, humidity, engine and transmission wear and production differences, etc. pp. You'd basically need to take a yellow car, run measurements under controlled conditions, strip down the paint, repeaint in red, rerun the experiment, strip down the paint, repaint in yellow and add a second rerun to exclude wear factors. Have fun with that ;-)

A priori one can never determine what are relevant and what are irrelevant side conditions in science.

It was Galilei who recognized: In empty space all masses fall down
with the same speed. Though, in the normal situation with air
around, their speeds are different. It is not easy to state what
the different speeds depend on.
Galilei’s law of falling body showed
its fundamental insight and importance for future mechanics only
under idealized side conditions.

If science shows that certain phenomena do not depend on certain
side conditions, it does so by changing the experiment.
To design
clever experiments is one of the tasks of experimental science.
E.g., currently experiments in neuroscience clearly illustrate the
necessity of careful designed experiments.


In your example: If one has a plausible hypothesis why electromagnetism may depend on the named factors, then a corresponding test has to be designed. But only after one has raised funds :-)

I believe Galileo fuzzled a bit with the experimental data. It's really his thought experiment (two falling bodies connected with a little string) that is (imo) illuminating. I was a physics teacher in a high school for a while and one my joys was to see the light bulb flash on when pupils "got" this -- especially when they inititally had the intuitive sense -- which most people have -- that heavy objects fall faster.

+1 Viagra was originally developed as a heart medicine. One of the "irrelevant details" was that it caused erections.

@IdiosyncraticSoul, I would call that a financially beneficial side effect.
